# Testing Batchable QueryLocator for managed package

Tags: schedulebatch

I am refactoring a project for someone and they make use of Batachables in a few classes. While all of these classes compile, they fail in testing due to the QueryLocators containing the fully qualified name of the fields as if they were in a managed package. This namespace doesn't exist in my test environment.

```
//Assume xxx is the name space
string query = 'select Id, xxx__Field1__c, xxx__Field2__c,xxx__Field3__c;
```

I assume these queries would be OK once the package is deployed and the namespace is applied to the field name, but while in testing is there anything I can do? Can this be safely ignored and I should just do a test deployment and see what the tests do?

I should also add, this version I am working on is the Unmanaged version of the package(obviously), and once complete it will be turned into the managed version.

Here is a very old blog post that seems to highlight this issue:
http://bracketlabs.com/blog/2011/7/25/salesforces-apex-namespace-requirement-creates-barrier-to-co.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one. You should be ok to just go ahead and ignore the failed tests, but then any breakages you create will only be discovered when you try and deploy to the packaging org.

I do this myself with certain parts of our products where dealing with the non-namespaced issue is just too cumbersome or would require to much additional code that I'd rather was not added as it's uneeded outside of the development org.

Comment: That was what I had figured. I assume some type of logic could be implemented to use a different query string when in testing, but then you'd lose out on code coverage since you still wouldn't be able to properly test the production code. Thanks!